# How can I redirect users to login page and then add item to wishlist?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

If a person clicks on add to wish list, would it be possible to redirect them to the login screen if they are not logged in and then add the item to the wish list after they login? If so, how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a variable through the url relating to that items unique id and a second variable to add to wishlist between the pages. Inside your code check for those variables and redirect where necessary